# Plot multiple subplots as animations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation, plot

I have two separate `subplots` that I'm hoping to display as animations. For the subplots below, `ax1` displays an animated `scatter` plot, while `ax2` is a scatter now, I'm hoping to alter this to a `line` `plot`.

Please note: I've simplified the question to only display relevant info. However I'm hoping to keep the code similar to what it is now.

Below is my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

DATA_LIMITS = [0, 15]

def datalimits(*data):
    return DATA_LIMITS 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,18))
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 3, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)

gridsize = (3, 2)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax1.grid(False)
ax2.grid(False)

ax1.set_xlim(DATA_LIMITS)
ax1.set_ylim(DATA_LIMITS)

line_a, = ax1.plot([], [], 'o', c='red', alpha = 0.5, markersize=5,zorder=3)
line_b, = ax1.plot([], [], 'o', c='blue', alpha = 0.5, markersize=5,zorder=3)
lines=[line_a,line_b] 

scat = ax1.scatter([], [], s=20, marker='o', c='white', alpha = 1,zorder=3)
scats=[scat] 

line_d = ax2.plot([], [], 'o', c = 'k')

ax2.set_ylim(-6,6) 
ax2.set_xlim(0,15) 

def plots(tdf, xlim=None, ylim=None, fig=fig, ax=ax1):

    df = tdf[1]

    if xlim is None: xlim = datalimits(df['X'])
    if ylim is None: ylim = datalimits(df['Y'])

    for (group, gdf), group_line in zip(df.groupby('group'), lines+scats+line_d):
        if group in ['A','B','D']:
            group_line.set_data(*gdf[['X','Y']].values.T)
        elif group in ['C']:
            gdf['X'].values, gdf['Y'].values
            scat.set_offsets(gdf[['X','Y']].values)

    return [scat] + [line_a,line_b] + [line_d]          

n = 9
time = range(n)  

d = ({
     'A1_X' :    [13,14,12,13,11,12,13,12,11,10],
     'A1_Y' :    [6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,10],
     'A2_X' :    [7,6,5,7,6,3,4,5,6,6],
     'A2_Y' :    [11,12,11,10,11,12,10,11,10,9],
     'B1_X' :    [8,9,8,7,6,7,5,6,7,6],
     'B1_Y' :    [3,4,3,2,3,4,2,1,2,3],
     'B2_X' :    [13,14,14,14,13,13,13,12,12,12],
     'B2_Y' :    [5,4,3,2,4,5,4,6,3,3],
     'C1_X' :   [5,6,7,5,6,5,6,5,6,5],
     'C1_Y' :   [10,11,10,11,12,11,10,8,7,6],
     'D1_X' :   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],           
     'D1_Y' :   [0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,-1],                
    })

tuples = [((t, k.split('_')[0][0], int(k.split('_')[0][1:]), k.split('_')[1]), v[i])
    for k,v in d.items() for i,t in enumerate(time) ]

df = pd.Series(dict(tuples)).unstack(-1)
df.index.names = ['time', 'group', 'id']

interval_ms = 1000
delay_ms = 2000
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plots, frames=df.groupby('time'), interval=interval_ms, repeat_delay=delay_ms,)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 3:** I've deleted all previous updates to keep things clean; you can still check them out in the edit history.

See if this code does what you want, changes are marked via comments:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np #<< a new import is required

DATA_LIMITS = [0, 15]

def datalimits(*data):
    return DATA_LIMITS 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,18))
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 3, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)

gridsize = (3, 2)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (0, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(gridsize, (2, 0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax1.grid(False)
ax2.grid(False)

ax1.set_xlim(DATA_LIMITS)
ax1.set_ylim(DATA_LIMITS)

line_a, = ax1.plot([], [], 'o', c='red', alpha = 0.5, markersize=5,zorder=3)
line_b, = ax1.plot([], [], 'o', c='blue', alpha = 0.5, markersize=5,zorder=3)
lines=[line_a,line_b] 

scat = ax1.scatter([], [], s=20, marker='o', c='white', alpha = 1,zorder=3)
scats=[scat] 

line_d = ax2.plot([], [], '-', c = 'k') ##<< using '-' makes this a line plot

ax2.set_ylim(-6,6) 
ax2.set_xlim(0,15) 

def plots(tdf, xlim=None, ylim=None, fig=fig, ax=ax1):

    df = tdf[1]

    if xlim is None: xlim = datalimits(df['X'])
    if ylim is None: ylim = datalimits(df['Y'])

    for (group, gdf), group_line in zip(df.groupby('group'), lines+scats+line_d):
        if group in ['A','B']: #<< 'D' is moved to a new if case
            group_line.set_data(*gdf[['X','Y']].values.T)
        elif group in ['D']:
            if tdf[0]==0: #<< use this to "reset the line" when the animation restarts
                          ## or remove the if/else part here if you want continuous (over-)plotting
                group_line.set_data([0,0])
            else:    
                _x,_y=group_line.get_data()
                _x=np.append(_x,gdf['X'].values)
                _y=np.append(_y,gdf['Y'].values)
                group_line.set_data([_x,_y])

        elif group in ['C']:
            gdf['X'].values, gdf['Y'].values
            scat.set_offsets(gdf[['X','Y']].values)

    return [scat] + [line_a,line_b] + [line_d]          

n = 9
time = range(n)  

d = ({
     'A1_X' :    [13,14,12,13,11,12,13,12,11,10],
     'A1_Y' :    [6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,10],
     'A2_X' :    [7,6,5,7,6,3,4,5,6,6],
     'A2_Y' :    [11,12,11,10,11,12,10,11,10,9],
     'B1_X' :    [8,9,8,7,6,7,5,6,7,6],
     'B1_Y' :    [3,4,3,2,3,4,2,1,2,3],
     'B2_X' :    [13,14,14,14,13,13,13,12,12,12],
     'B2_Y' :    [5,4,3,2,4,5,4,6,3,3],
     'C1_X' :   [5,6,7,5,6,5,6,5,6,5],
     'C1_Y' :   [10,11,10,11,12,11,10,8,7,6],
     'D1_X' :   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],           
     'D1_Y' :   [0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0,-1],                
    })

tuples = [((t, k.split('_')[0][0], int(k.split('_')[0][1:]), k.split('_')[1]), v[i])
    for k,v in d.items() for i,t in enumerate(time) ]

df = pd.Series(dict(tuples)).unstack(-1)
df.index.names = ['time', 'group', 'id']

interval_ms = 1000
delay_ms = 2000
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, plots, frames=df.groupby('time'), interval=interval_ms, repeat_delay=delay_ms,)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Asmus. Apologies I should have mentioned in the question that it should adhere to the code. I have trimmed down the question for SO purposes. But my actual code contains greater functionality that requires the code to be setup as is.

Comment: @jonboy well than you're issues are only (a) your `line_d` has only *one* coordinate (perhaps you want a .scatter() instead?) (b) you're not putting `line_d` into `lines`, hence it won't be animated inside your `for (group, gdf), group_line …` loop.

Comment: @jonboy I've updated my answer at the top to show you the four lines you need to add/change instead.

Comment: Thanks @Asmus. This works well. I must be confusing the line plot. I do want an animated similar to the one called in your first answer answer. `D_X` indicates which frame it is and `D_Y` displays the relative value. So instead of the `*` animated scatter, I'd like the same values to be displayed as an animated line plot.

Comment: @jonboy "I do want an animated similar to the one called in your first answer answer" <— do you mean you want a scatter plot here (for group D) instead?  By the way I just realized you need to change `scat.set_offset` to `group_line.set_offset()` and perhaps give `scat` a color other than white, in order to see it.

Comment: @jonboy just in case, I've made another **Edit** above to show you how to handle group 'D' as a scatter plot.

Comment: I think we are getting confused here. group `A,B,C` are all scatter plots, which go into `ax1`. group `D` is a line plot, which will go into `ax2`.

Comment: @jonboy you initially created `line_a` and `line_b` via `ax1.plot()` (which is commonly used to plot *lines*, but *can be used* to plot only markers [see docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)) and `scat` as an actual `.scatter()` plot of group `C`. If you want to have `D` as a *line plot* (again, requiring `.plot()`!) you would have to first `.get_data()` from `line_d`, append the "current value" for each animation step, and then `.set_data()` (see original answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193829/discussion-between-jonboy-and-asmus).